# Jenkins not deleting old branches from multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins

When scanning my multibranch pipeline, I am expecting old branches that are deleted from bitbucket to get deleted in Jenkins.
This is the output of scanning my pipeline:

```
Evaluating orphaned items in *****
Will remove ****
Will remove ****
Finished: NOT_BUILT
```

But it doesn't remove the branches.

I have Prune setup and orphaned setting are all set to empty

Edit:
Tried to add `extensions: [[$class: 'PruneStaleBranch']]` to my checkout step, it still doesn't remove old branches

Comment: We have started seein this as well, and this was working before.  We currently are narrowing it down, but we did a lot of plugin upgrades a little while back, and that may have been the root cause.  Have you done any plugin upgrades?